# How to be more anonymous and safe on Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, anonymity, security, settings

Is it possible to more anonymous and on Tor than this setup and browsing method:

- Using Tails OS from USB which stores no data on hard drive
- Using Tor browser on safest mode
- Always automatically updating Tor browser
- Using NordVPN on top of Tor (Connecting to NordVPN first then Tor)
- Not installing any additional addons, plugins, or themes
- Not using JavaScript
- Not using P2P file sharing
- Blocking HTTP Websites and only using a secure connection
- Not logging into any account like (Gmail, facebook, etc.) and only using for sure anonymous accounts
- Never posting any personal information
- Not purchasing anything which could expose my identity
- Not downloading any file which could expose my identity
- Not browsing the internet on another browser simultaneously
- Only using public hotspots (since your home wifi could potentially leak data and check out: https://www.reddit.com/r/TOR/comments/8x7dwj/why_public_wifi/)
- Using DuckDuckGo Onion search engine only

?

The main reason to use Tor is to be anonymous so that nobody can track you on the internet and find out who your real life identity. So its useful to have the best configuration possible for the Tor browser when using it. I've heard an argument against having a VPN with Tor is safer since the VPN provider can see your IP address and can give your data away. So, is it safer to have a Tor over VPN connection or a VPN over Tor connection? It's a personal preference, but there are definitely advantages and disadvantages to both. Additionally, should this list be changed for mobile users or if the user is using the Onion browser  (thank you @user610620)?

Comment: Not using home internet where any leaks of your IP would lead feds straight to your doorstep, but instead only connecting to public wifi hotspots

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that, I will add that too!

Comment: whats bad about resizing the Tor browser window? and its ok to log into anonymously-made accounts, you mean just don't log into personal accounts

Comment: @user610620 the defualt Tor browser window size is the what most people use and with a different window size, you could be fingerprinted. Websites can figure out your device/OS if you are in fullscreen. Not even blocking JavaScript protects against this since you can find the window size with CSS. Also, I added only allowing anonymous accounts.

Comment: Tor browser uses [letterboxing](https://support.torproject.org/tbb/maximized-torbrowser-window/) now so you can resize the window.

Comment: wonder how much your list also applies to the Tor mobile browser for android

Comment: @Steve, that only works if the user doesn't maximize or fullscreen their window according to the Tor Project.

Comment: @user610620 I added a question on whether this list is the same for mobile.

Comment: @Swangie Where do you see that? Letterboxing also works when maximizing or using fullscreen.

Comment: @Stever, I misread, my bad - I will add to update the Tor browser automatically since the older versions didn't have that

Comment: If Tor browser anonymizes our IP address, why go to extra lengths to not use Tor from home? What added benefit does going to a public wi-fi hotspot even provide a Tor user? Does it simply defend against the fact that our ISP at home could have logs showing that we are running Tor browser from home (but not the .onion sites we're on)? Or is there more to this step? How and why would Tor fail to randomize our IP? that would make it a faulty product

Comment: @user610620, I've heard people say its best to use Tor on a public hotspot - again, there are a lot of conflicting information on using Tor safely, so it was my mistake - I didn't exactly know whether this was right or not so I just included it. Also, you stated in the first comment that you shouldn't use home Wifi as leaks could make you traceable.

Comment: Why did you remove it. it was me who suggested it be added, but I'm just trying to understand why people say so. it should still be kept on the list

Comment: @user610620 I added it back, I wasn't sure what you meant so I accidentally removed it. But I added it back. Check out this post also for more info: https://superuser.com/questions/398776/tor-public-wi-fi-safe
I agree, I'm not sure why people think using public wifi is safe, so I will have to research it.

Comment: Also, I was wondering if using another ".onion" search engine was better since DuckDuckGo technically collects some anonymous statistics, but maybe there was another .onion search engine which collected almost no data.

Comment: DuckDuckGo, despite having its own .onion page, does not browse the darknet, only the web. Which search engine are you talking about

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119205/discussion-between-swangie-and-user610620).